# Linux SHELL script, read each row for different number of columns

Tags: linux, bash, shell, sh

I have file and for example values in it:

```
1 value1.1 value1.2
2 value2.1
3 value3.1 value3.2 value3.3
```

I need to read values using the shell script from it but number of columns in each row is different!!!
I know that if for example I want to read second column I will do it like this (for row number as input parameter)

```
$ awk -v key=1 '$1 == key { print $2 }' input.txt
value1.1
```

But as I mentioned number of columns is different for each row.
How to make this read dynamic?

For example:
if input parameter is 1 it means I should read columns from the first row so output should be

```
value1.1 value1.2
```

if input parameter is 2 it means I should read columns from the second row so output should be

```
value2.1
```

if input parameter is 3 it means I should read columns from the third row so output should be

```
value3.1 value3.2 value3.2
```

Th point is that number of columns is not static and I should read columns from that specific row until the end of the row.

Thank you

Comment: What does "dynamic" mean specifically, to you? What do you want to happen when your "second column reader" encounters a one-column row?

Comment: @Dejan, please do mention expected sample output too in your post.

Comment: There's no problem reading varaible #columns. The point is what you want to do with them. It will be appreciated if you can illustrate with example data and expected output.

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 I updated. Thank you

Comment: @tshiono I updated. Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Then you can simply say:

```
awk -v key=1 'NR==key' input.txt
```

**UPDATED**

If you want to process with the column data, there will be several ways.
With awk you can say something like:

```
awk -v key=3 'NR==key {
    for (i=1; i<=NF; i++)
        printf "column %d = %s\n", i, $i
}' input.txt
```

which outputs:

```
column 1 = value3.1
column 2 = value3.2
column 3 = value3.2
```

In awk you can access each column value by `$1`, `$2`, `$3` *directly* or by `$i` *indirectly* where variable `i` holds either of 1, 2, 3.

If you prefer going with bash, try something like:

```
line=$(awk -v key=3 'NR==key' input.txt)
set -- $line    # split into columns

for ((i=1; i<=$#; i++)); do
    echo column $i = ${!i}
done
```

which outputs the same results.
In bash the *indirect* access is a little bit complex and you need to say `${!i}` where `i` is a variable name.

Hope this helps.

Comment: thanks. And just one small question - how can I read value by value when I have output for example for the third column value3.1 value3.2 value3.2 and now I would like to process one value by one (I need to take and parse one value by one)

Comment: please if you can just add how to read value by value - one by one from this output (for example value3.1 value3.2 value3.3)

Comment: I updated my answer.  Please take a look and if something is unclear please let me know.